# probabilities combinations

Tags: math, matlab, combinatorics

I faced a problem while writing a code in Matlab that calculates sum of products of all possible combinations of n numbers taken from a vector with length m. It is similar to the task that you will drag exactly n different balls out of the bag with m balls (order doesn't matter).

example:
m = 5, n = 3 then i need to calculate sum of 10 summands

thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `nchoosek`.

```c
m=5;
n=3;
s=sum(nchoosek(1:m,n), 2);
```

Comment: thank you very much, nchoosek is exactly what i need to continue my work

Comment: @Kate, in that case, could you [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) the answer, please ?